# How can I calculate the compression of a ball?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, collision, elasticity

I was thinking about elastic collisions, and then I thought, What causes more compression in a ball when it's hit? Is it the velocity of the thing hitting the ball? Does the mass of the thing hitting the ball have something to do with the compression?

Here is an example:

Imagine a golf ball is hit by an object of $1 \text{kg}$, then we do the same experiment but with an object of $1000 \text{kg}$.
The velocities are the same in the collision ($10$ $\text{m/s}$) but the mass is not. Will the ball have the same compression in both cases?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

the constraint  force F between the club and the ball is proportional to the momentum during the collision :

$$p=\int F\,dt\quad,\text{with}\\
p=2\,{\frac {m_{{2}}\,m_{{1}}{\it u_1}}{m_{{2}}+m_{{1}}}}$$

where

- $u_1~$ start velocity of the golf club
- $m_1~$ mass of the golf club
- $m_2~$ mass of the golf  ball
- $p~$ linear momentum during the collision $~\left[\frac{\text{kg m}}{s^2}\right]$

thus if $~m_2\mapsto f\,m_2~$ you obtain that

$$\frac{p(m_2=f\,m_2)}{p}=\frac{p_f}{p}=\underbrace{{\frac {f \left( m_{{2}}+m_{{1}} \right) }{fm_{{2}}+m_{{1}}}}}_{\kappa}$$

hence the ball compression is $~\kappa~$  time grater then if   $~\kappa~$ equal one ($f=1$)

$$p_f=\kappa\,p$$

Comment: Does the KE of the collision has to do with the compression of the ball or it's just the force?

Comment: Just the force  the compression is the force divided by the stiffness of the ball

Comment: Sorry i don't understand your math well, How can you calculate the force of impact if the velocity is constant?

Comment: The start velocity $u_1$ Is constant what you don’t know is the time that the collisions take

Comment: What is p? Net force?

Comment: @Y-9b8z please see new document edit

Answer (score 0):

The compression of an elastic ball is proportional to the applied force. At the moment of the collision the portion of the ball in contact with the object is forced to move immediately with its velocity, while the rest of it is accelerated by the force of compression.

Eventually, that acceleration results in an increase of the ball velocity that exceeds the object velocity, and the ball detaches.

During a given time $\Delta $ before they loose contact, the reaction force results in a decrease of the momentum of the object. As $\Delta p = m \Delta v$, a bigger $m$ results in a smaller reduction of velocity for the same decrease of momentum.

So, during that same time, the contact velocity keeps greater for a bigger mass, resulting in a bigger force and a bigger compression.

Comment: Thanks, so this means the bigger the mass of the object hitting, the bigger the compression of the ball?